# Как ввести два значения через пробел в массив через textbox с#?

Tags: c#, массивы, winforms, textbox

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int n = 0;
        n = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        int[] mass = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < mass.Length; i++)
        { 
            int S = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
            mass[i] = S;
        }
        textBox3.Text = mass[0].ToString();
    }
```

Имеется данный код, при вводе в textBox1 числа (длину массива), а в textBox2 элементы массива через пробел выводится ошибка "Входная строка имела неверный формат". Предполагаю это из-за введённого пробела. Как это исправить?

Comment: `.Text.Trim()` уберет лишние пробелы по краям

Comment: А зачем вводить длину, если ее можно определить по количеству введенных чисел? `int[] numbers = textBox2.Text.Split().Select(int.Parse).ToArray();`

Comment: Нужно ввести размер массива, а потом максимально заполнить этот массив числами, не используя методы

Comment: Какие методы? `int.Parse` это метод, `ToString` это метод.

Comment: Извините, без методов, которые нельзя изобразить на "блок-схеме"

Comment: Что угодно можно отобразить на блок-схеме

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй это:

```
var numbers = textBox1.Text.Split(' ');
List<int> lst = numbers.Select(item => int.Parse(item)).ToList();
```

Будет еще лучше, если вы будете использовать такую ​​группу методов:

```
List<int> lst = numbers.Select(int.Parse).ToList();
```

Comment: Автор говорил, что ему Linq не подходит. Типа преподаватель хочет, чтобы он сам реализовал алгоритм.